# how to close applet on button click

Tags: java, applet

How to close applet from code
I have used **System.exit(0)** but it only throws bunch of exceptions and it did not closes it.
I understand that it is responsibility of the user to close applet , but still is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't** call `System.exit(0)` in an applet. This can cause the browser to be closed.

A better approach would be to run application in a `JFrame` and use [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html) to launch the application.

Comment: i am using appletviewer and not any browser for displaying applet

Comment: Why not convert your applet into an application then? Then it is fine to call `System.exit(0)`.

Answer (score 2):

In the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` method, call..

```
// end the applet by navigating to the 'applet ended' URL
applet.getAppletContext().showDocument(appletCloseURL);
```